# Why does adding a sleep to a bash script seem to break variable decrementing for certain named variables?

Tags: bash, special-variables

With the following bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
let SECONDS=5

until [[ "$SECONDS" -le "1" ]]; do
    echo SECONDS $SECONDS
    (( SECONDS -= 1 ))

#    sleep 1
done
```

I am seeing strange behavior. Namely, that if I uncomment the `sleep 1` the loop continues but the counter does *not* decrement, I see output like:

```
$./mvce.sh 
SECONDS 5
SECONDS 5
SECONDS 5
SECONDS 5
SECONDS 5
SECONDS 5
SECONDS 5
```

Removing that line results in the expected:

```
$./mvce.sh 
SECONDS 5
SECONDS 4
SECONDS 3
SECONDS 2
```

I'm not really sure why this is happening. I can rename the variable to something else and things work as expected so it seems that something about `sleep` breaks my `SECONDS` variable.

This was surprising, why does calling sleep override the `SECONDS` variable within my script?

Comment: `SECONDS` is a special/reserved shell variable and shouldn't be used in user applications

Comment: See paragraph 4 of http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html -- all-caps names are used for variables meaningful to the shell and POSIX-specified tools; lowercase names are reserved for application-defined use.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy can you post that as an answer, that's basically what I was looking for here!

Comment: ...frankly, it looks to me like @anubhava has written a pretty good answer -- if you want to let them know what part of the question they aren't covering that I touch on in my comment above (maybe the link into the POSIX spec?), letting them update their question to cover it probably makes as much sense as adding something that would be mostly-duplicative.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Save in a variable the number of seconds a process took to run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/858594/save-in-a-variable-the-number-of-seconds-a-process-took-to-run)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`SECONDS` is reserved variable in shell. That's why you must always use **lowercase or mixed case variables** in your script and avoid using all uppercase variable names.

```
#!/bin/bash
let secs=5

until [[ "$secs" -le "1" ]]; do
    echo SECONDS $secs
    (( secs -= 1 ))

   sleep 1
done
```

That gives expected output:

```
SECONDS 5
SECONDS 4
SECONDS 3
SECONDS 2
```

Doumentation:

> SECONDS
>                 Each time this parameter is referenced, the number of seconds since shell invocation is returned.  If a value is assigned
>                 to  SECONDS,  the  value returned upon subsequent references is the number of seconds since the assignment plus the value
>                 assigned.  If SECONDS is unset, it loses its special properties, even if it is subsequently reset.